# How to tackle asynchronous nature of javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, asynchronous, callback

I have a simple HTML form . I am trying to do a series of validations for the form using javascript .

```
$("#sign_in_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(check_validity()){
        console.log("valid");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("invalid");
        return false;
    }

    console.log("end of function");    
});
```

Now `check_validity()` is a time consuming function . It checks data from the database and then replies with true or false. But the above function doesn't seem to wait for `check_validity` to complete and runs the `else` statement, before the check validity is complete.

How do I fix this? Probably using a callback function can fix this. But how do I receive a return value using callback?

```
function check_validity(){
    $.post("http://xxxx.com/check_if_user_exists",
    {email: $("#contact_person_email").val()},
    function(data){
        if(parseInt(data) == 1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: you need to do it using a callback. it is the return value of what that you are having trouble receiving?

Comment: How do I receive the result of check_validity() while using a callback ?

Comment: Did you write check_validity? It's not that javascript is by nature asynchronous, it's that check_validity is returning false without completing the database query.

Comment: Yeah . I wrote check validity . It doesnt return false without finishing the DB query . It returns true if the form is valid, but by then the above function is already complete .

Comment: Updated the code with check_validity function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jquery deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/):

```
function check_validity(){
    return $.post("http://xxxx.com/check_if_user_exists", {
        email : $("#contact_person_email").val()
    }).then(function(data) {
        return parseInt(data, 10) != 1;
    });  // end of post 
} //end function
```

Usage:

```
check_validity().done(function(valid) {
    if (valid) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

But you still won't be able to use it to decide on whether to return `true` or `false` in `submit()`. It's just impossible for async calls.

Comment: The problem is not the callback, but how to handle the submit event.

Comment: @Bergi: and I mentioned in the last phrase that it's not possible to do with asynchronous requests.

Comment: Hey @zerkms - This works !! Thanks .. Whats the difference in my code and yours ?

Comment: @mad.geek: your `check_validity()` always returns `undefined`.